# Rewrite to relative path in Apache2 on Mac OS X Lion (10.7)

Tags: php, macos, mod-rewrite, apache2, relative-path

I've searched the site thoroughly and Googled for this as well, but to no avail.
I use Apache2 + PHP on my Mac OS X.
I haven't changed much of the configuration on any of them, just enough to get everything working correctly.
Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteBase /~milad/mysite/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?:url [L,QSA] #Handling tail with no parameters

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?:url=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

This works just fine for all the files located at `http://localhost/~milad/mysite/*`.
But I want to make my `.htaccess` file independent of my installation's particulars, i.e., I don't want to have to include the `RewriteBase ...` line in my code.

But when I remove that line, Apache tries to map it to a URL which I don't understand.
What I get is:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Users/milad/Sites/newave/index.php was not found on this server.

which is just ridiculous, because the `index.php` file is JUST where that URI is pointing to.
Anyway, when I try to rewrite to `/index.php` instead of `index.php`, I find that it is being rewritten to `http://localhost/index.php`. So how is it that I can't use just the relative path, or just use `./index.php` (Yes, I've tried that, too).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the .htaccess file sitting in the document root (where http://localhost/ points to) or where /~milad/mysite/ points to?

Comment: The latter. It is located at `/~milad/mysite/`

Comment: To be specific, it is at `/Users/milad/Sites/mysite/.htaccess`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from your vhost configuration:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /Users/milad/Sites/newave/index.php was not found on this server.
```

Means clearly: "the base of your site is **`/Users/milad/Sites/newave/`**".
So if you want the base for you site to be **`/~milad/mysite/`** try to change the DocumentRoot

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/~milad/mysite/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Of course, all the files of you site must be in the folder "`/~milad/mysite/`".

Then in your htaccess file (notice that `^(.*?)$` is equivalent to **`(.*)`** and I don't understand why you need the `RewriteRule ^$` because it should be handled properly at the end):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?:url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please tell me if it works

---

Edit: Following the comments, here's a vhost file that works for me:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/web/htdocs/olivier/wwog"
    ServerName wwog.fr
    ServerAlias *.wwog.fr

    ErrorLog "/web/logs/wwog.error.log"
    CustomLog "|/opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs /web/logs/wwog/access.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S.log 5M" combined

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm

    <Location />
        # Compression:
        # (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)
        # Insert filter
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
        \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </Location>

    # Add "Cache-control: public" = valid for 480 weeks
    # for proxies to keep images in cache:
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Forbid files that start with "_"
    <FilesMatch "^_">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy all 
    </FilesMatch>

    # Forbid .htaccess and .htpasswd
    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy all 
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/web/htdocs/wwog">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from none
        AllowOverride All 
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My `DocumentRoot` is set to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, so that is where `http://localhost` leads to. But my personal web-site for my current user is `/Users/milad/Sites/`, so `http://localhost/~milad/` leads there. I don't know how this is configured as such, but that's not my real problem anyway.

Comment: Just found out that the settings is configured using the `UserDir` directive in the `mod_userdir` module.
Thanks for the regexp pointers, though.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.
It seems that having both a relative rewrite and the mod_userdir enabled is not going to work.
Looking at apache2 logs, I have found out that when I execute the `RewriteRule` statement, Apache tries to locate a file at `/Users/milad/Sites/mysite/index.php`, but instead of trying to take it as an absolute path, it tries to find it inside the `DocumentRoot`.
The error is:
    File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/Users

Comment: I'm pretty sure you take it the wrong way. First question (no offense): do you know how to setup virtual hosts? If no, that's the first step before doing anything else (including trying to rewrite URLs).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I do. But I was trying to keep the changes to the original `httpd.conf` provided by Lion minimal. I have now set up my own `VirtualHost` at `localhost:90` so as not to disrupt the other sites residing at `:80`, and things seem to work as I expected them to.

Comment: No offense, but you shouldn't have to do such manipulation if you configuration is setup properly. I guess there's something that is not right *but it's not a rewriterule problem*. Something about vhost configuration and global configuration (maybe you forgot something in your global configuration that is applied to each vhost or something like that (it often happens to me)).

Comment: Here's what I usually do: write a full vhost config with a servername that doesn't exist for real, for example : `zz123.com`. Then add in your `etc/hosts/` file `127.0.0.1   zz123.com`. And here you go: launch Firefox, go to `zz123.com` and it should display your local website.

Comment: Thanks. Did that. Works right for me.
Also, I noticed that Apple sets its httpd.conf in a manner that the default DocumentRoot is used for anything that doesn't begin with `~username`. So, if I rewrite something to a location that doesn't begin with `~username`, Apache tries to look it up in the `DocumentRoot` specified globally.

Comment: Ok I've add a real vhost sample that works for me. Try to copy paste, change to your need and tell me if you still have a problem

Comment: This works for me. Thanks.
But if the context path starts with `~` and the next token is a valid username, Apache still tries to map it to my ~/Sites folder (i.e., `wwog.fr/~milad` is mapped to `/Users/milad/Sites/`).
So, in the end, I guess I have to stop using the userdir module for the installation location of my website.
Thanks for the VHost though, works great. Especially the additions (compression, caching, etc.)
I think I need to